# Can not copy files to a new directory - TypeError: os.PathLike object

Tags: python

I am iterating through files in a folder (input) and do some operation and save the results to new files in a new folder (output). However, ending up with this error.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mask_class_modifier.py", line 28, in <module>
    shutil.copy(x, new_mask_dir)
  File "/Users/g/miniconda2/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 244, in copy
    dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
  File "/Users/g/miniconda2/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 146, in basename
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

**code**

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image
import shutil
import numpy as np

mask_dir = "input/"
new_mask_dir = "output/"

# change the class number of masks in each image
results1 = []

for filename in os.scandir(mask_dir):
    if filename.path.endswith(".png"):
        image = Image.open(filename.path)
        mask = np.array(image)
        mask[mask==3] = 50, 
        mask[mask==4] = 51
        results1.append((filename.path, mask))

# copies files with masks to a new directory
for x in results1:
    shutil.copy(x, new_mask_dir)
```

Reproducible code

```
mask1 = Image.open(urlopen('https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3885659/78411130-24eee380-75fe-11ea-831c-84ca2eae82ac.png'))
mask2 = Image.open(urlopen('https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3885659/78411130-24eee380-75fe-11ea-831c-84ca2eae82ac.png'))
mask3 = Image.open(urlopen('https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3885659/78411130-24eee380-75fe-11ea-831c-84ca2eae82ac.png'))

masks_list = [mask1, mask2, mask3]

new_masks=[]

for x in masks_list:
  mask = np.array(x)
  mask[mask==3] = 50, 
  mask[mask==4] = 51
  new_masks.append(mask)
```

Comment: You're creating a tuple with `(filename.path, mask)` and calling the tuple in `shutil.copy` but shutil copy only takes the string paths of the file to be copied and the destination to copy it to. Also, you're not saving the new masks to the original file or the copy.

Comment: The ```append``` function would save the new masks and shutil would copy them to a new folder no?

Comment: The append function does not save the mask back to the original image which is a file. `shutil.copy` copies files from one place to another, it does not overwrite information to files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do. You were not saving the original image with the new mask and `shutil` does not save the mask to a new file either. `append` only adds a value to the end of a list. If you're trying to save the image with the new mask try the code below. In this instance, I've used a file name as a key in a dictionary, but you can just use the original file name.

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image
import shutil
import numpy as np

mask_dir = "input/"
new_mask_dir = "output/"

if not os.path.exists(new_mask_dir):
    os.mkdir(new_mask_dir)

for filename in os.scandir(mask_dir):
    if filename.path.endswith(".png"):
        image = Image.open(filename.path)
        mask = np.array(image)
        mask[mask == 3] = 50
        mask[mask == 4] = 51
        masked_img = Image.fromarray(mask)
        new_img_path = os.path.join(new_mask_dir, filename.name)
        masked_img.save(new_img_path)
```

Comment: thank you but what if the `imgs` is a folder with a list of many files?

Comment: Then read them in the same way you were. Bring in a list, get the filename, etc. Look at the last three or four lines of my code and work that into yours.

Comment: I get empty output when I replace the last three lines in my code with `masked_img = Image.fromarray(mask)
        new_img_path = os.path.join(new_mask_dir, filename)
        masked_img.save(new_img_path)`

Comment: I edited to make my answer fit your first non-reproducible code block.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is this line `results1.append((filename.path, mask))`. The use of double brackets means you are adding a tuple to the list `results1`. When you then iterate over that list, x becomes a tuple and the `shutil.copy` function cannot take a tuple as it's first parameter.

To fix your error, remove the `, mask` in the `results1.append` line. You don't need to add the mask to the list, because you aren't using it later. Removing this, stops this being a tuple and means the function will work as expected when copying.

Another solution, allowing you to retain the presence of the mask in the list would be to add `[0]` after the `x` in the copy function call to specify that you are wanting to use the first item in the tuple (the filepath).

If you want to save the new image instead of making a copy, change the final line to be `Image.fromarray(x[1]).save(new_mask_dir+x[0])`, which saves the new image as the new file. When doing this, ensure the `results1.append` line is exactly as it was before this answer, when it was giving you an error (it won't anymore)

Comment: I am not getting the error but the output is the same as the input. It didn't perform the operation that I am trying to do within the loop.

Comment: Edited now, see my final paragraph for that

Comment: Throwing this error ```AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'```

Comment: Add Image.fromarray() to the x[1] as shown in the answer now

Comment: Error - ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:``` I am sure there are no files missing.

Comment: What is the value of x[0]? Can you print it and comment its value here

Comment: I added a reproducible code. Please take a look. It is very similar to the code except it doesn't copy files to a new folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210921/discussion-between-incarnadine-and-ferrelwill).